# Adding to a Queue using an Azure function in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I have the following function:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")]HttpRequestMessage req,             
    TraceWriter log,
    [Queue("myqueuename")] ICollector<string> queue)
{
    . . .
    queue.Add(msg);
```

When I invoke this, I get no error, and the function appears to run correctly (I'm running it locally from VS atm).  However, the queue in question doesn't get added to.

Looking around the web, I've seen at least one example that suggests using the BrokeredMessage class might work.  I've tried using `BrokeredMessage`:

```
BrokeredMessage bm = new BrokeredMessage(new test() {test1 = msg});
queue.Add(bm);
```

This gives an error saying it can't read `DeliveryCount`.

This leaves me with two questions: firstly, should this work using `ICollector<string>` (and if so, what have I done wrong)?  The second question relates to `BrokeredMessage` - it seems to exist in a Nuget package called `ServiceBusv1_1` which has a description that makes me think it is not intended for this purpose: is that the correct package?

Comment: Did you try adding the queue as an outputbinding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Queue` attribute means Azure Storage Queue, not Service Bus. Use `ServiceBus` attribute instead.

With that, both `string` and `BrokeredMessage` outputs should work fine.

You can walk through examples in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#output---attributes).

Comment: Thanks - for anyone else looking for the same thing - the Nuget package is https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.  However, for the release version, there is a dependency on a beta release of https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/3.0.0-beta4 for some reason